# C Expected Output Failure

Tags: c, output

Here is my program.I am trying to find the frequency of each character of a string and display it. While answering please see to it that I don't want to try the ASCII concept and I want to know whats wrong with this concept.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
int l=0,j,k,m,count[10000];
char string[10000];
printf("Enter the string : \n");
scanf("%s",string);
l=strlen(string);
printf("%d",l);
for(j=0;j<l;j++)
    {
        for(k=j+1;k<l;k++)
        {
            if(string[j]==string[k])
            {
                count[j]++;
            }
        }
    }
for(m=0;m<l;m++)
    {
       printf("%d",count[m]);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's the expected behavior, and what's the actual behavior? Add it to the question.

Comment: What do you mean by ASCII concept?

Comment: What's wrong is `count[10000];` requires `9872` more integers (and `39488` bytes of stack space) than counting every ASCII character using the "ASCII method".

Comment: Question is still missing a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you wish to find the frequency of  characters in your string.

About the mistakes in your code:

- Consider the string `lalal` Here you would be counting the last `l` twice, once corresponding to first `l` and second time corresponding to third `l`. Hence your logic is faulty.
- Similar is the case of `count[]`. You haven't initialized the array hence it holds **garbage values**.

So another approach to your problem could be declaring a 26-element array(English alphabet), iterate through the entire list and increment count corresponding to each element when that element is found.

```
int frequencyChar[26] = {0};//stores frequency of characters [a-z], initialized to zero

for( i=0; i<strlen(str); i++) //iterate through the entire string
{
    frequencyChar[str[i] - 'a']++; //increment count corresponding to each element
}

for( i=0; i<26; i++) 
{
    printf("%d\n",frequencyChar[i]);
}
```

P.S.Above code assumes only lowercase characters in string. Minor changes would allow inclusion of uppercase letters!

Answer (score 1):

Here are the problems:

1. You have written: `I am trying to find the frequency of each character`, but you code is attempting to calculate histogram of correlations between pairs of characters.
2. as an index for `count` you are using `j`, which iterates over constitutive characters in string. This means that your table `count` have lots of `0` and only some `1` and nothing else.
3. So currently this is NOT histogram of pairs of characters nor histogram of characters.

Character histogram can be created like this:

```
void makeStrHistogram(char *str, int histogram[256])
{
    memset(histogram, 0, sizeof(histogram));
    while (*str) histogram[*str++]++;
}

void printHistogram(int histogram[256])
{
    for (int i=0; i<256; ++i) {
       if (histogram[i]) {
            printf("%c - %d\n", (char)i, histogram[i]);
       }
    }
}
```

To generate character correlation matrix:

```
void correlationMatrixForStr(char *str, int matrix[256][256])
{
    memset(matrix, 0, sizeof(matrix));
    int len = strlen(str);
    for (int i=0; i<len; ++i) {
        for (int j=i+1; j<len; ++j) {
            matrix[i][j]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ... The FGITW effect leads to spelling error in answers.